# Relational Databases: Is it fine to have a foreign key referencing an Associative table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Lets say we have Passengers, where Passengers can attend many Flights, and one Flight may have many Passengers. In each Flight, each Passenger has a unique selection of Movies he/she can watch.

For Passengers, Flights, and the association between them, we have three tables:

```
Flights 
-----------
id
flight_number

Passengers
--------
id
name

PassengerFlights
---------------
passenger_id
flight_id
```

For Movies, it must specify for which Passenger and for which Flight will it be available to.

In this case, is it fine to reference the PassengerFlights junction table with a foreign key, or would it be better to create a junction table with three foreign keys(passenger_id, flight_id, movie_id)? For example:

### Option #1

```
MoviePassengerFlights
---------------------
movie_id
passenger_flight_id
```

### Option #2

```
MoviePassengerFlights
----------------------
movie_id
passenger_id
flight_id
```

The concern I'm having with Option #2, which seems the most straightforward, is that it remains a valid record even if the relationship between a Passenger and Flight gets deleted.

Would Option #1 or Option #2 be recommended for such use cases? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Hi codeintern — I know you’re a new user — if you find that one of us answered your question, please mark that as the accepted answer (check mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> junction/join table

In the Relational paradigm, there is no such thing.  The term is **Associative table**.  It *associates* two parent tables, and resolves a many-to-many relationship between them.  `JOIN` is an SQL verb.

> The concern I'm having with Option #2, which seems the most straightforward, is that it remains a valid record even if the relationship between a Passenger and Flight gets deleted.

That is false.  If "the relationship between a Passenger and Flight gets deleted", the Passenger is no longer on that Flight, therefore there is no Flight-Passenger for which the Passenger can make reservations for Movies.

Worse still, if the relationship between a Passenger and Flight is **not** deleted, you can reserve Movies for any old Passenger for any old Flight ... which is incorrect: Movie reservations should be constrained to Passengers who are actually on a specific Flight, a PassengerFlight.

I do not see how that is at all "straight-forward".

> Would Option #1 or Option #2 be recommended for such use cases?

For your declared files:

- Option 1 is correct.
- Option 2 is grossly incorrect.

That is also the generic answer for such "use cases".

> Is it fine to have a foreign key referencing an Associative table?

The answer is yes.  It is very common in Relational databases, once you get past a few tables.  Each table is a Fact, each relationship is one between two Facts.  An Associative table is just a Fact, which can be referenced by any subordinate Fact.

> Or is there a better alternative?

Yes.  A Relational database. Your declared files are not Relational, they are a typical 1960's, pre-relational, Record Filing System, deployed in SQL for convenience.  That is not entirely your fault: the great mass of "literature"; all the textbooks, that are marketed by "theoreticians" and sundry authors, that purport to be "relational" are in fact anti-relational.  What they labour over is what they understand: 1960's, pre-relational RFS, "relational" only in name.  It is a massive tragedy.  Relational databases have far more Integrity; Power; and Speed.

That is beyond the scope of the Question.  Feel free to ask another Question, and I will answer it.

Answer (score 1):

The select depends on when the passenger purchases the movies. If they can only purchase a movie onboard, then Option #2 would be fine since you wouldn't expect the passenger/flight relationship to be deleted after the flight started.

If, on the other hand, the movies could be purchased in advance, and you want to refund the purchase if the passenger cancels their reservation, then Option 1 would assure that you can't delete the flight record if a movie purchase still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Consider if it is possible to enter a row in `passenger_flight_movie` for a
movie which is not available on that flight, or for a passenger not booked on that flight. This is oversimplified, but shows constraints.

```
-- Movie MOVIE_ID exists
--
movie {MOVIE_ID}
   PK {MOVIE_ID}


-- Flight FLIGHT_ID exists
--
flight {FLIGHT_ID}
    PK {FLIGHT_ID}


-- Passenger PASSENGER_ID exists.
--
passenger {PASSENGER_ID}
       PK {PASSENGER_ID}


-- Movie MOVIE_ID is available on flight FLIGHT_ID.
--
movie_flight {MOVIE_ID, FLIGHT_ID}
          PK {MOVIE_ID, FLIGHT_ID}
         FK1 {FLIGHT_ID} REFERENCES flight {FLIGHT_ID}
         FK2 {MOVIE_ID}  REFERENCES movie  {MOVIE_ID}


-- Passenger PASSENGER_ID is booked on flight FLIGHT_ID.
--
passenger_flight {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID}
              PK {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID}
             FK1 {FLIGHT_ID}    REFERENCES flight {FLIGHT_ID}
             FK2 {PASSENGER_ID} REFERENCES passenger {PASSENGER_ID}


-- Movie MOVIE_ID is available to passenger PASSENGER_ID
-- on flight FLIGHT_ID.
--
passenger_flight_movie {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID, MOVIE_ID}
                    PK {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID, MOVIE_ID}

                   FK1 {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID} REFERENCES
      passenger_flight {PASSENGER_ID, FLIGHT_ID}

                   FK2 {MOVIE_ID, FLIGHT_ID} REFERENCES
          movie_flight {MOVIE_ID, FLIGHT_ID}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your concern that the m_p_f record could remain even if the passenger is no longer booked on the flight — in the p_f table, make the combination of (flight_id, passenger_id) the compound primary key of that table, and reference that as the foreign key in the m_p_f table, using an ON DELETE CASCADE rule. Then if the record is deleted from p_f, the corresponding records in m_p_f will be automatically deleted by the engine.